# Battery status shows background activity but background app refresh and location permissions are off

Tags: ios, facebook, apns

As an iOS developer, I am extremely curious about this case: Battery usage on my iPhone 6 (iOS 8.1) shows that the main reason of battery draining on my phone are Facebook and Twitter, both have a label "Background activity" below their names.

I used to think, that this label is shown when the app does background app refresh, but that option is switched off on my phone. There is one other way to have the app run in the background: background location updates. Since neither of these two apps have this authorized at me, this can't be the reason. (And GPS icon was not shown either.)

So my question is: How is it possible to have Facebook and Twitter app running code in the background without background app refresh and location permission?

Comment: This is very disappointing as Facebook clearly has more permissions than Apple allows. Guess you can pay for anything now a days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enable your iPhone as developer mode, connect your iPhone to the Xcode and Instruments, you can monitor how these app running.

also, you can check the info.plist file of these apps.

Twitter running a shot of time and no longer wakeup
[image]

Facebook App wakeup time to time
[image]

Comment: I can't monitor what these apps are doing, just the information if they are running or not.

Comment: running back ground usually cause Voice over IP,play audio video stream or stream,background download,remote notification e.g

Comment: active monitor you can check information from all running processes

Comment: You are right, `info.plist` includes voip background mode, which can explain the situation.

Comment: On the other hand, Twitter.app has only `fetch` background mode.

Comment: if I disable background refresh, twitter app suspend the background task after running in background a short while and no longer wakeup again. but the Facebook wake up period of time. I add two screenshot

Comment: This doesn't answer the question...